# Need an anchor link that only moves Overflow text box without Scrolling Browser

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, overflow, anchor

I'm trying to figure out a way of clicking an Anchor link TEMPLATES
on the top of my page without having the browser scroll to the point of my anchor.

Sounds redundant huh?

Wait.

My anchor link is inside of a overflow: Hidden text box where clicking the Anchor link 
at the top of my page should only raise the anchor in the Overflow text box displaying it's 
content, like having a new webpage. From a layout perspective the browser must always be at the top of the page where my form is.

Anyone have a clue?
Thanks

UPDATE:::

Oh spoke to soon, looks like the Css and Javascript - Show and Hide method would be more adequate.
Found here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/dhtml/a/aa101507.htm

Thank internet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy do so. What you are trying to do is to have a parent div/view which would act as the main div and all the other divs/views will be loaded or unloaded within it dynamically or so as its children. It would better to employ a design pattern such as "MVC", but it can be done via JQuery straight up. If I was to tackle something like this, I would have a "navigation view" and then content views so when a user clicks on the desired navigation link, that particular view will be loaded or scrolled in. (Of course, you need to experiment and line your depths as desired for the content views).

This is how Flash is programmed. This is a very high level explanation, and I hope it gives you somewhat of an idea about getting it going.